# Squarespace Code Block Alignment Issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, codeblocks, squarespace

We have custom coded animate flipping cards on our website. There is an issue with the alignment and sizing of them. The issue only occurs when there are multiple cards on the page (they are made using code blocks). You can see the issue on the link below.

Any help would be appreciated!

[LINK TO SITE](http://agreementpictures.com/team-flip/)

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/csx6fcrs/) (ONLY 1 CARD...ISSUE DOESN'T SHOW UP)

HTML:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('focus');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front-brian">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="centerize">
        <div class="socicon-style">
          <a href="imdb.com">
            <span class="socicon-imdb">
        </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="back-title">Brian Perry</div>
        <div class="role">CEO</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

    background: #bd2d2c;
}







.flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;


}




.flip-container:hover .flipper,  
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }








.flip-container, .front-brian, .front-tony, .front-blaine, .front-alex, .front-eric, .front-sue, .front-tamara, .front-kenyon, .front-dom, .front-lt, .front-lindsey, .front-chris, .front-ethan, .back {
  width:6000px;
  min-height:100%; 
  max-width:100%;
  max-height: 10000px;
   height:0;
   padding-bottom: 70%;

}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front-brian, .front-tony, .front-blaine, .front-alex, .front-eric, .front-sue, .front-tamara, .front-kenyon, .front-dom, .front-lt, .front-lindsey, .front-chris, .front-ethan, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100;
}







.front-brian{
    background: url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/573e762945bf219b6da541d1/t/57a5d191e3df28ea3c3f9bfb/1470484886737/Brian+Headshots-29.jpg);

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}


.back-title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    text-align: center;
}

.role {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be occurring because you have nested blocks. That is, each code-block ( `.code-block` ) is nested within the previous one, so each image is slightly more padded than the one before.

See the attached image.
[Nested Squarespace Code Blocks - Dev. Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3XWh.jpg)

I'm not sure how this problem was created. Did you copy and paste code containing `sqs-block code-block sqs-block-code` elements? It appears that you did, at least at first glance.

To fix this, you're going to need to remove all of the Squarespace-specific divs that wrap each of your `flip-container` divs. Within the code block, all you should have is a series of `flip-container` divs, one after another. Like this:

```
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('focus');">etc</div>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('focus');">etc</div>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('focus');">etc</div>
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('focus');">etc</div>
```